# Where would I find the kernel .config file in Linux ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm copying my kernel config file from an existing system to the kernel tree, and I entered this command:

`/boot/config$(uname -r)`

Yet I got:

`bash: /boot/config-5.15.0-46-generic: Permission denied`

Does anyone know why its saying permission denied and how to fix? I am using Ubuntu in VirtualBox.

Comment: I entered this command: "/boot/config$(uname -r)" - You are trying to **execute** configuration file, which is useless: the file is not intended for execution.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tsyvarev mentioned in comments it is possible that you're trying to execute file, that have no exec permissions:

```
$ ls -l /boot
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    217414 Aug 20  2021 config-5.4.0-rc1+
...
```

Try to run: `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r)` to read the config file for currently running kernel.